# How does de-icing work in an airliners engine

Tags: airliner, engine

On snowy days the pilots well say to put on the de-icing on both engines how does this work?

Comment: I don't think the other question answers regarding the engine sufficiently. I  would like to answer and say that the crew will normally turn on anti ice whenever they are in visible moisture, the main thing that it does is apply heat to the engine EPR (exhaust pressure ratio) sensors at the front and rear of the engine to prevent ice build up. This allows the engine to continue making the correct thrust in accordance with its thrust lever position. An interesting link is here http://www.boeing-727.com/Data/systems/infoicerain.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, hot bleed air from the engine is ducted around the engine to prevent ice from forming. It is also directed through valves and ducting to the leading edges of the wings.